# BLE Scanner for just mobile devices?

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to develop an app that finds how many people are around you using ble connection. Currently, i'm able to see every device around me, but I wanted to know if I can filter just mobile phones.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

BLE doesn't work like that. BLE is just a connection standard that allows devices, regardless of type, to communicate with one another in a manner that is standardized. Similar to JSON for API endpoints, JSON works for any type of device that consumes that data.

To make more sense of this iOS has a `CBCentral` and `CBPeripheral` object types, which each have specialized functions and methods.

- `CBCentral` can be thought of as a "Brain" that allows connecting via the manager, disconnecting, etc..
- `CBPeripheral` can be thought of as a broadcast station, a remote device if you will, that can broadcast information or act as, for example, a remote speaker.

Without knowing exactly what your use case is, there's no way to "Filter to mobile devices only." However if you have an app that is attempting to communicate with another device, that happens to be running the same app, you can do some things with the `Advertiser` which would allow you to filter to those specific devices. For example, you may have many different peripherals being detected nearby with names ranging from `ABXDY131-device-aha` to `742494-speaker-os` which would appear, and in fact should be treated as, completely random. When you setup your own broadcast with and advertisement, you can prefix some specific text to it `yourAPPIdentifier-asdfasdfj114515` and `yourAPPIdentifier-akj1415151-phoneOS` which would allow you to look at all nearby connections and filter specifically on the one that has that prefix text.

I encourage you to look through Apple's documentation on the matter so you can better understand how/why things work the way they do. I'll warn you, Core Bluetooth is `NOT` for beginners. You must be ready to deal with tons of edge-cases, async calls, and in general it's fairly advanced. There are several libraries that can assist with easing this, but if you're in it to learn it, learn from the ground up.

#### Resources

- Apple Docs - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth
- SwiftyBluetooth - https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyBluetooth